# Can not convert a parameter of type BINARY(16) into expected type VARCHAR(40) in Snowflake

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes, azure-synapse

I am trying to join two tables in the below query in Snowflake.
And it is throwing me the below error since, tst1.id is varchar and tst2.id is binary

```
Can not convert a parameter tst2.id of type BINARY(16) into expected type VARCHAR(40)
```

My Query:

```
Select tst2.id, tst1.id 
from test1 as tst1
inner join test2 as tst2
on tst1.id = tst2.id
where tst2.id ::binary = '18374683274748987' :: binary
and tst2.date :: date >= '2022-06-20' :: date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot encode to binary directly strings, they need to be in a HEX format, so this won't work:

```
select '18374683274748987' :: binary;

The following string is not a legal hex-encoded value: '18374683274748987'
```

but this will:

```
select to_binary(hex_encode('18374683274748987'), 'HEX');

TO_BINARY(HEX_ENCODE('18374683274748987'), 'HEX')
3.138333734363833323734373438393837e+33
```

In your case try:

```
Select tst2.id, tst1.id 
from test1 as tst1
inner join test2 as tst2
on tst1.id = tst2.id
where tst2.id = to_binary(hex_encode('18374683274748987'), 'HEX')
and tst2.date :: date >= '2022-06-20' :: date;
```

Comment: It is still throwing me this error "Can not convert parameter 'tst2.id' of type [BINARY(16)] into expected type [VARCHAR(40)]" @Sergiu

Comment: How does tst2.id looks like if you select it?

Comment: select * from tst2 where tst2_id = md5_binary('998823475837465839');  This one works fine. But with the join its throwing an error. @Sergiu

Answer (score 0):

So if we start with no ON/WHERE's and just get the data types correct in some example data:

```
WITH test1(id) as (
    select * 
    from values
        ('18374683274748987'::varchar)
), test2(id, date) as (
    select to_binary(hex_encode(column1)), column2::date 
    from values
        ('18374683274748987', '2022-06-20')
)
Select 
    tst2.id as bin_val, 
    tst1.id as text_val
from test1 as tst1
join test2 as tst2
```

| BIN_VAL | TEXT_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 3.138333734363833323734373438393837e+33 | 18374683274748987 |

so that ON join `on tst1.id = tst2.id` will cause the error

> Can not convert parameter 'TST2.ID' of type [BINARY(8388608)] into expected type [VARCHAR(16777216)]

because the type are wrong, so that should become:

```
    on to_binary(hex_encode(tst1.id), 'HEX') = tst2.id
```

and thus the WHERE needs the same transform, and thus this SQL works for the noted input:

```
WITH test1(id) as (
    select * 
    from values
        ('18374683274748987'::varchar)
), test2(id, date) as (
    select to_binary(hex_encode(column1)), column2::date 
    from values
        ('18374683274748987', '2022-06-20')
)
Select 
    tst2.id as bin_val, 
    tst1.id as text_val
from test1 as tst1
join test2 as tst2
    on to_binary(hex_encode(tst1.id), 'HEX') = tst2.id
where tst2.id = to_binary(hex_encode('18374683274748987'), 'HEX')
and tst2.date :: date >= '2022-06-20' :: date;
```

| BIN_VAL | TEXT_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 3.138333734363833323734373438393837e+33 | 18374683274748987 |

I put some other things in expecting needing to show that `TRY_TO_BINARY` should be used by `null` and `'this is not hex string'` actually where handled, so I am at a loss to prove, the `TRY_` versions should be used, but it also depends if you want your code to silent move on, or explode when the input is different than you expected.

Comment: I am getting the error "syntax error line 5 at position 1 unexpected ','" @Simeon Pilgrim